# Renaming set of files on a schedule

Tags: batch-file

I have three files in one folder

```
AODH 30-9-2015 DEEL 1.mp3
AODH 30-9-2015 DEEL 2.mp3
AODH 30-9-2015 DEEL 3.mp3
```

I want them automaticaly (on sunday) renamed to

```
AODH DEEL 1.mp3
AODH DEEL 2.mp3
AODH DEEL 3.mp3
```

How can I do this?
I'm struggling with the code

```
@ECHO OFF 
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
 FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN ('dir /b *" ??-??-???? DEEL 1.mp3"') DO ( 
 SET "oldName=%%a" 
 SET "newName=!oldName: ??-??-????=!" 
 ECHO Rename !oldName! to !newName! 
 REM RENAME "!oldName!" "!newName!" 
 )
```

THIS WORKS:

for %%a in ("AODH * DEEL *.mp3") do (
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=. " %%b in ("%%a") do (
        ren "%%a" "AODH DEEL %%b.mp3"
    )
)

Comment: can you expand on what your struggling with.

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('dir /B *.mp3') do ren "%%a %%b %%c" "%%a %%c"`

Comment: The string replacement expansion syntax does not support wildcards as you are trying, so the line `SET "newName=!oldName: ??-??-????=!"` fails as it want to remove the _literal_ string portion ` ??-??-????` (that is, replace it by an empty string); instead, you could use something like `set "newName=!oldName:~,4! !oldName:~16!"`, when the first and second name portions are always of same length...

Answer (score 0):

For the three files mentioned in your question the entire code would be:

```
for /L %%a in (1,1,3) do ren "AODH 30-9-2015 DEEL %%a.mp3" "AODH DEEL %%a.mp3"
```

A slightly more universal version that accepts any date in the file names and any number of files:

```
for %%a in ("AODH * DEEL *.mp3") do (
    for /f "tokens=4 delims=. " %%b in ("%%a") do (
        ren "%%a" "AODH DEEL %%b.mp3"
    )
)
```

To schedule the batch file use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7).